# Need to connect to a SQLEXPRESS database with PHP 7 / Apache

Tags: php, apache

I'm running a website with PHP 7 and Apache. Currently building a tool on the website that will need to interface with a SQLEXPRESS database. What modifications will I need to make to my PHP install in order to connect to this database?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Using CentOS7 on Media Temple

Comment: Connecting MS SQLServer with php on linux server is very tricky. The only driver supported is pdo_odbc. Which to make this works you should install freetds first as odbc connector to windows sql server. The best way to connect php with MS SQL SERVER is run the php under windows environment. There are sqlsrv driver. Its only supported for windows unfortunately.